# why does it say TypeError : 'cluster' object is not callable even when callable(cluster) gives true

Tags: python, tree, typeerror

The following are my class definitions :

```
class logline:
    def __init__(self,t,cmp,msg):
        self.t = t
        self.cmp = cmp
        self.msg = msg

class cluster:
    clusters = []
    def __init__(self,status,log):
        self.status = status
        self.children = []
        self.eventlogs = []
        self.rep_msg = log.msg
        self.addLog(log)
        self.prev = None
        if(status == 'root'):
            cluster.clusters.append(self)            
    def prev(self):
        return self.prev
    def print_children(self): 
        for child in range(0,len(self.children)):
            print(self.children[child].rep_msg)
            self.children[child].print_logs()
    def print_logs(self):
        for log in self.eventlogs:
                print(log.msg)
    def add_child(self,status,log):
        temp = cluster(status,log)
        self.children.append(temp)
        temp.prev=self
        return temp
    def addLog(self,log):
        self.eventlogs.append(log)
```

Now, tree is my root cluster node

`tree = cluster('root',log1)`

and prev is my child cluster node added to tree

`tree = tree.add_child('child',log6)`

When I try:
`tree = tree.prev()`
I should get back tree, but it gives me the error:

```
tree = tree.prev()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'cluster' object is not callable
```

On the other hand :
`callable(cluster)`
evaluates to true

my class definitions are based off of: [How can I implement a tree in Python? Are there any built in data structures in Python like in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358045/how-can-i-implement-a-tree-in-python-are-there-any-built-in-data-structures-in/23451186#23451186?newreg=cf086fe57a77495cb1b054f20bf5edd2)

I've searched around but can't seem to find anything which matches my situation

Thanks in advance

**Edit :**
So, I am an absolute beginner in python, I should have probably led with that

```
>>> print(tree)
<__main__.cluster object at 0x02AF8590>
>>> print(tree.prev)
<__main__.cluster object at 0x02AEA270>
```

I'm assuming since I'm getting different locations for both statements, prev has been set to something
But I'm not able to go back to my parent node with
`return self.prev`

Comment: BTW, you code would be easier to read if you put a blank line after each method definition. Also, you should use the [PEP-0008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) naming conventions and give your classes CamelCase names, eg `Cluster` and `Logline` or `LogLine`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cluster` class itself is callable: when you call it it returns an instance of the class. However, an *instance* of the class *isn't* callable. But (you may ask) why is your code even trying to call an *instance* of the class?

Well, that's because the `.add_child` method returns the new `temp` instance, but it sets the `temp.prev` attribute to `self`, the parent instance. And that overrides the `.prev` *method* of that instance. So when you do `tree.prev()` it's trying to call that parent instance instead of the `prev` method.

Incidentally, the `cluster.__init__` method also replaces the `.prev` method with `None`.

So you need to get rid of that name clash. I suggest you rename the attribute to `._prev`.

Answer (score 0):

`prev` is an attribute of your `cluster` instance `tree` (overriding the method of the same name).

`cluster`'s constructor `__init__` is what makes the `cluster` class callable. But when you instantiate the `cluster` class using `__init__` you get an *instance*. This instance is not callable, unless you implement a `__call__` method in your class.

To check this:

```
callable(cluster) #Returns True
callable(tree) #Returns False
```