# How to replicate a file tree as a Python list?

Tags: python, list, file, directory

I need to replicate the functionality of a file directory tree as a list. I have to be able to search for specific "documents" through the "folders". All of which may contain duplicate names at other depths. I also have to be able to dynamically add new files and folders during runtime. So for example, a file tree like this:

```
MyFiles
    Important
        doc1
        doc2
    LessImportant
        doc3
        doc4
    LowPriority
        Important
            doc1
        LessImportant
            doc4
```

If I use nested lists, the above tree would end up looking like:

```
[MyFiles,[Important,[doc1,doc2],LessImportant,[doc3,doc4],LowPriority, 
[Important,[doc1],LessImportant,[doc4]]]]
```

And then I would have to run loops through all the nests to search for stuff and use .append to add new "folders" or "documents".

Is there a better / more efficient way than nested lists?

Comment: Do you need to distinguish between files and directories?

Comment: And: Do you need to get the path of the file your looking for as well?

Comment: If you need a tree-like structure, this might help: [How can I implement a tree in Python? Are there any built in data structures in Python like in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2358045/2745495).

Comment: Have you considered using [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#elementtree-objects)? It might be an over kill but will give search and iterate functions for free.

Comment: I don't need to distinguish between files and directories, I just need to be able to find the "files" that are organized via the "directories"

Answer (score 1):

Using [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) gives search and iterate functions.

```
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def ls(p):
    if os.path.isdir(p):
        node = ET.Element(os.path.basename(p), type='dir')
        node.extend([ls(os.path.join(p, f)) for f in os.listdir(p)])
    else:
        node = ET.Element(os.path.basename(p), type='file')
    return node
```

Then testing this by writing out as XML as that is quite easy from ElementTree:

```
root = ET.ElementTree(ls(r"C:\test\Myfiles"))

from xml.dom import minidom
def pp(tree):
    print ''.join(minidom.parseString(ET.tostring(tree.getroot())).toprettyxml(indent='  ').splitlines(True)[1:])

pp(root)
```

Gives

```
<Myfiles type="dir">
  <Important type="dir">
    <doc1 type="file"/>
    <doc2 type="file"/>
  </Important>
  <LessImportant type="dir">
    <doc1 type="file"/>
    <doc2 type="file"/>
  </LessImportant>
  <LowPriority type="dir">
    <Important type="dir">
      <doc1 type="file"/>
    </Important>
    <LessImportant type="dir">
      <doc4 type="file"/>
    </LessImportant>
  </LowPriority>
</Myfiles>
```

You'll can play around to decide if the `dir` or `file` should be an element tag or attribute.

Answer (score 0):

What about such a structure using the dict datatype:

```
{"ID": 0, "Type": 'Folder', "Name": 'MyFiles', "Subdirectories": [1, 2, 3]}
{"ID": 1, "Type": 'Folder', "Name": 'Important', "Subdirectories": []}
{"ID": 2, "Type": 'Folder', "Name": 'LessImportant', "Subdirectories": []}
{"ID": 3, "Type": 'Folder', "Name": 'LowPriority', "Subdirectories": [4, 5]}
{"ID": 4, "Type": 'Folder', "Name": 'Important', "Subdirectories": []}
{"ID": 5, "Type": 'Folder', "Name": 'LessImmportant', "Subdirectories": []}

{"ID": 0, "Type": 'File', "Name": 'doc1', 'ParentDirectory': 1}
{"ID": 1, "Type": 'File', "Name": 'doc2', 'ParentDirectory': 1}
{"ID": 2, "Type": 'File', "Name": 'doc3', 'ParentDirectory': 2}
{"ID": 3, "Type": 'File', "Name": 'doc4', 'ParentDirectory': 2}
{"ID": 4, "Type": 'File', "Name": 'doc1', 'ParentDirectory': 4}
{"ID": 5, "Type": 'File', "Name": 'doc4', 'ParentDirectory': 5}
```

Which would let you parse the data in a recursive manner. Here the files are numerated seperately from folders. Each file has the Parentdirectory entry which is the current directory the file is in. The folders have a list of subdirectories and all elements are linked through the ID datafield.

Answer (score 0):

#### The OOP Approach

At first sight you might get the impression "Nah, that's too many lines of code" but it does have some great advantages (e.g. you're way more flexible).

**Class / Basic Construct**

```
class FileOrFolder:

    def __init__(self, name, children=None):
        self.name = name
        self.children = children if children else []

    def search_for(self, f_name):
        global hits  # defined later on

        for child in self.children:

            if child.name == f_name:
                hits.append(child.name)

            if child.children:
                child.search_for(f_name)
```

**Recreating the File Tree**

```
TREE = FileOrFolder("MyFiles", [
    FileOrFolder("Important", [
        FileOrFolder("doc1"),
        FileOrFolder("doc2")
    ]),
    FileOrFolder("LessImportant", [
        FileOrFolder("doc3"),
        FileOrFolder("doc4")
    ]),
    FileOrFolder("LowPriority", [
        FileOrFolder("Important", [
            FileOrFolder("doc1")
        ]),
        FileOrFolder("LessImportant", [
            FileOrFolder("doc4")
        ])
    ])
])
```

**Application & Ouput**

```
>>> hits = []
>>> TREE.search_for("doc4")
>>> print(hits)

['doc4', 'doc4']
```

**NOTE:**
However, I don't know if your overall goal is to simply create a file tree manually or automatically iterate through an existing&real one and "copy it". In case it's the latter you would need to make some slight changes.