# reading a txt file numbers line by line and turning each line into a multi linked list in python

Tags: python, linked-list

using python I want to create a multi-linked list that each node on the main body that can have two pointers. one to the next node on the main body and one to a branch-linked list.

my input is a text file that has the main body elements at the start of each line at its branches at that line with a space in between.

example:

10 15 58

13 18 25 20

14

12 55

now I want a linked list that has 10->13->14->12 as its main body and 10 for example has 10->15->58 as its branch linked list.

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour] and read [ask] to improve, [edit] and format your questions. Thanks

Comment: It seems that you are looking for a tree.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358045/how-can-i-implement-a-tree-in-python

Comment: *"I want to create a multi-linked list"*: how is it going? Did you write any code? If so, what is the problem with it? If not, then what is the question?

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code? Show FULL error message in question (not in comments) as text (not image)

Comment: You can use list of lists in python, using the `append()` of list. So, you could have [ [10,15,58], [13,18,25,20], [14], [ 12,55] ] , then you can access it as listOflists[2][1], to get the first element of your 2nd list - i.e 13

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.