# How to create a parent/child relationship to then create a family tree in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am attempting to make a "family tree" from a JSON file. I have managed to create functions that find the identifiers of each object, as well as each of its children:

Identifiers: ['a6g#', '84&3', 's5%9', '2@98']

Respective Children: [['84&3', 's5%9', '2@98'], None, None, None]

I am attempting to figure out a way to 'connect' all of these elements so that I can use some sort of graphing module that will show 'a6g#' on top, and then underneath it is connected to '84&3', 's5%9', '2@98'. I will need to be able for the parent node to connect to children which then connect to the parent node's grandchildren, and to its children, so on and so forth.

If anyone has any ideas, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: A very simple method might be to implement a dictionary containing each member of the family, and for each family member storing a list of its children. Given the lists you've given us above you could create it with: `{parent: child for parent, child in zip(identifiers, children)}`

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39292920/15521392) could be interesting for you.

Comment: @Rabinzel this looks exactly like what I am looking for! Thank you so much.